# Why VLQ flag on answer was declined?

Tags: support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30592845/) as VLQ, before it was marked as accepted. And this flag was declined.

Sure, the answer is accepted and maybe it was a reason to declining this flag by moderator. But, in my view the quality is really low, and the same recommendation/answer/hint is in comment under question, which came first and is upvoted by 5 users.

So, the point of this question isn't primarily to change moderator's decision and confirm the flag. I only want to know what is really VLQ answer if not unformatted 'answer' with good idea but with no comment why, a little bit abstract (without context) and probably copied from comment above?

The same post with higher quality should be, for example:

> Use `position: fixed` to fix element on viewport/screen when you scroll
>
> ```
>     div {position: fixed}
> ```
>
> http://... [Link to info about position as a bonus here]

Answer (score 2):

It's not low-quality enough to warrant outright deletion. It provides an answer in the shortest sentence possible (if you'll forgive the lack of punctuation). And at least it's in an answer, not a comment.

Comment: On one hand there are users which write _put comment to your code_ when you have code-only answer. On the other hand, this answer is okay. Really don't know how to understand it.

Comment: @panther: The problem with code-only answers is that sometimes you can't tell if the code is meant to answer the question, or if it's an edit or some random code dump. The answer you link to is quite clearly an answer to the question. That said, a moderator would not respond to a VLQ flag on either answer with immediate deletion. If you think the answer sucks, downvote it. I know I would, but it seems someone else has touched it up now.

Answer (score 2):

You are aiming your vote wrong, the problem is the question.  It is very trite and all he had to do is copy/paste the question title in the Google query box.  He would have found [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334495/center-div-in-the-middle-of-the-screen-even-when-page-is-scrolled-up-down), the top hit back then.

The answer is correct.

The fact that SO is being used today for "Can you Google this for me?" questions is a tremendous problem that has no solution that SO users are willing to consider.  The question did not get a *single* close vote.  Well, it got mine, we need another 7 SO users.

Answer (score 0):

Your question demonstrates that the answer was *indeed* salvageable.

As a reminder, the VLQ flag reads as follows:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: You mean the formatting and the content at all are okay in this case? How _severe formatting_ looks? There has to be many bolds, shouts, etc. to be qualified as severe formattings? Missed formatting is okay?

Comment: @panther: The description says "salvageable", not "okay". Why do you keep conflating the two?

Comment: @panther I would say VLQ is for when it doesn't qualify as NAA, but is utterly terrible.

Comment: @panther Upon encountering this answer, I would have edited it—as I already have—and considered upvoting it (were I not out of votes for the day).